# How to execute an NUnit test method from command line that has been data driven with TestCaseSource attribute?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

I have a data driven test method that looks something like this:

```
[TestCaseSource(typeof(TestDataGetter), nameof(TestDataGetter.GetUniqueAccessionNumbersAndLoginsForToolbarItems))]
public void TCID37452(string accessionNumber, string loginId)
{
//run test steps
}
```

When this gets populated in Visual Studio Test Explorer, I see multiple test methods with the appropriate test data that was retrieved from TestDataGetter.GetUniqueAccessionNumbersAndLoginsForToolbarItems()
They look something like this in the test explorer:

- TCID37452("x", "123")
- TCID37452("y", "124")
- TCID37452("z", "125")

I would like to run one of these methods with the test data using NUnit command line. However, I cannot figure out how to do this. It seems as though I can only run by test method name, but I can't specify the parameter values. This results in all of the test iterations being executed and not just one.

Thanks in advance for your help.